# using GPS location service. What simulator behave should be?

Tags: iphone, gps

My task is - to figure out, if there is GPS module available on the device. I'm using 
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] for this. 
   But, question is - is this normal, that on simulator I have "true"? I think it should be "false". 
   Can anybody explain me, how this method works? Is this correct method for my task?

Comment: Is this question without any sense? Why it has no answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct method of checking if ths gps is enabled or not is using this if statement :

```
if (! ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) //chech for location of the device
|| ( [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)) 
//chech for the location of your current app
{
// the gps isn't enabled
} else {
// the gps is enabled
}
```

Comment: NB [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] is only for iOS 4.2 +  For anything below this you should use - (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error to check and turn off location tracking if required.